# Terminal can't get all tabs of all windows!

Tags: terminal, applescript, tabs

I am trying to iterate over every tab of every window in Terminal

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    repeat with t in tabs
    end repeat
end tell
```

output

```
execution error: Terminal got an error: Can’t get every tab. (-1728
```

Comment: Tab of what window?  Note that Terminal is just weird - what should be a tab is a window (and is even shown in the Window menu), and each window only has one tab.

Comment: @red_menace terminals can have multiple tabs. I am trying to iterate through all tabs of all terminal windows and check for their names of the tabs.

Comment: In Monterey anyway, if you make a new tab, although it may look like a tab, Terminal will list it as a window.  Each window will also have just one tab, so the whole window/tab thing doesn’t work right.  At the very least you will need to specify a window.

Comment: @red_menace when you do script in terminal it returns a tab. you can look at that tab as normal and setting the settings set changes the properties of that window via the tab. could you explain this in further detail?

Comment: @red_menace I updated my script to look at window names according to your specification that each tab is always a window. I am leaving the question up in case this is not always the case

Answer (score 2):

Tabs are an element of a window, so you can't just demand a list of tabs.

This will cycle through each open window and grab a reference to each tab in it. They will all end up in a list but they are not likely to be sorted.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    
    set xt to tabs of windows -- nested list of tabs
    set tList to {}
    
    repeat with win in xt -- each window
        repeat with tb in win -- each tab in above window
            
            set end of tList to contents of tb
            
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell

tList -- flat list of tabs
--> {tab 1 of window id 3824 of application "Terminal", tab 1 of window id 3568 of application "Terminal", tab 2 of window id 3568 of application "Terminal", tab 3 of window id 3568 of application "Terminal", tab 1 of window id 3564 of application "Terminal", tab 2 of window id 3564 of application "Terminal"}
```

Once you have a flat list, you can cycle through it (e.g. repeat with x in tList).

Comment: I learned that each tab is always in a different window 
```
tell application "Terminal"
 repeat with w in windows
  repeat with t in tabs of w
   set n to name of current settings of t
  end repeat
 end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

So apparently Terminal.app each tab is always it's own window. But if you really did want to iterate through the tabs instead of windows you can do so here. thanks to @red_menace for the help

```
tell application "Terminal"
    repeat with w in windows
        repeat with t in tabs of w
            set n to name of current settings of t
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Each tab is in a window, but there can be several tabs within one window. Basically the structure is the same as the one you see on screen.

Comment: @nohillside I never seen a terminal display multiple tabs in one visual tab. you can go ahead and use the log function with the tabs and it will only print one tab per window even though there are multiple visual tabs one one actual window.